# Best match search in Java

Tags: java, search, lucene, search-engine

I have DB table which stores list of all exceptions in Java and their description.
When the user inputs the exception name it retrieves the respective description. I have used Levenshtein distance to match strings incase they enter a wrong string, but I want to eliminate words irrelevant in a string search such as "and", "or" etc., from the input string, and to provide fast searching.

Is there an already existing framework or API for doing thing kind of searching on a list of strings?

Is there and better way to search for strings than Levenshtein Distance?

Comment: Bruce, already you asked this to Lucius Fox?

Comment: "and","or" etc. words are stopwords,to remove them simply get text file of such words from google and then find such words in your exception name input and remove them.

Comment: @swapnil7 i need more flexibility, i want the search to work even in the event for typos from the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you're kind of wrong. Words such as "and" and "or" are extremely relevant to the way some search engines work; furthermore, as you already know, Levenshtein distance is a common and effective metric allowing you to check the similarity between words. Also, using a (probably hashed) dictionary is almost as fast as it gets. Also, as already stated, if you really want to filter the input, define your rules for filtering, process the input, and *then* use the resulting string as a base for Levenshtein calculation.

Also, I'm kind of provoked to post a LMGTFY link here, since actually reading the Wikipedia article about Levenshtein gives you all the other information you may need. I'd suggest reading more about all the distance metrics and edit distances, there's not much I can add to the coverage already present in the below links.

source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%E2%80%93Fischer_algorithm